# Rules for setting hostname

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, hostname

It's thought that for the *hostname* should be used *FQDN*. I have a doubts about whether using:

`host.domain.ltd`

and

`domain.ltd`

for the *hostname* is the same thing and will be equally correct / acceptable?

I'm willing to use `domain.ltd` for the *hostname*.

Is it alright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[man hostname](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname)

> You can't change the FQDN (as returned by hostname --fqdn) or the DNS domain name (as returned by dnsdomainname) with this command. The FQDN of the system is the name that the resolver(3) returns for the host name.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "standard" rule for your hostname. It depends on many things, like your enviroment (domain or stand alone), your software(like zimbra requires host must have FQDN)...

Feel free to chose hostname, make it something meaning for you.